# How can i save multiple collections with some common data to database?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database, collections

I'm trying to save collections with part common data for all and different part for each collection. I wrote hard coded way to save one collection and I don't know how I can do it for multiple collections. So this is what I have:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MakeComplaint(CommonData model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {                    
        model.CreateComplaint();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class CommonData
{
    public string Data1 { get; set; }
    public string Data2 { get; set; }
    public List<DifferentData> Differents { get; set; }

    SecondModel DataContainer()
    {  //help needed here
        SecondModel tmp = new SecondModel();
        tmp.ID = Differents[0].ID;       //how can I change it to save more collections?
        tmp.Name = Differents[0].Name;

        tmp.Data1 = Data1;
        tmp.Data2 = Data2;

        return tmp;
    }

    public int CreateComplaint()
    {
        var complaint = DataContainer();
        db.AddComplaint(complaint);
        db.Save();
    }
}

public class DifferentData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How should my `DataContainer()` look in order to handle `Differents[1]` and more?

**EDIT:**
My `DataContainer()` is a list of objects now, so 1 problem solved

```
List<SecondModel> DataContainer()
    {   
        var listOfComplaints = new List<SecondModel>;
        for(int i = 0; i<Differents.Count; i++){
        SecondModel tmp = new SecondModel();
        tmp.ID = Differents[i].ID; 
        tmp.Name = Differents[i].Name;

        tmp.Data1 = Data1;
        tmp.Data2 = Data2;
        listOfComplaints.Add(tmp)
        }
        return listOfComplanints;
    }
```

**EDIT2:**
Working solution:

```
public void AddComplaint(List<SecondModel> model){
db.SecondModels.InsertAllOnSubmit(model) //saving multiple objects
}
```

Comment: You have to instantiate every different object you want to declare though they have common values so that it would reference to a different object in the memory

Comment: What kind of database? Relational ( Like SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite ... ) or NoSQL ( for example Document database like MongoDB ) ? This may have to be answered differently if one or the other.

Comment: @Fildor SQL Server, my code is working on 1 collection, i save values do database but i dont rly know how to modify `DataContainer()` to handle more collections

Answer (score 1):

Usually you get new Models from the page. Not as a DataContainer but as a SecondModel or another specific model.  Your DataContainer and nested classes in CommonData is probably adding confusion.  You can actually remove all of that, and use the code you have in AddComplaint directly from your controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MakeComplaint(SecondModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {                    
        db.SecondModels.InsertOnSubmit(model)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

and just do something similar for another model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MakeSomethingElse(ThirdModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {                    
        db.ThirdModels.InsertOnSubmit(model)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```